# Nested explicit wait does not work in Appium

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, android, waits

For example, I'm sending a message. While it's being sent to the recipient it has the resource-id "pending_indicator". When it is delivered, it has the resource-id "delivered_indicator".

So, I'm checking if the message is delivered using the following code:

```
List<MobileElement> messages = driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble")); // Get all messages in chat
MobileElement lastMessage = messages.get (messages.size () - 1);            // Get the last message

//Xpath query to check if the message has been delivered
String query = "//*[contains(@resource-id, 'delivered_indicator')]";

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy (lastMessage, By.xpath(query)));
```

But it does not work. I checked that the message has been delivered within 10 seconds, but the wait does not return anything. When I checked in IntelliJ evaluation mode, it showed that the `lastMessage` still has the "pending_indicator" resource-id in the "footer_delivery_status" container. Why is it not updated?

The `lastMessage` variable (message body) stays the same in app sources. It does not change itself, so it should not affect the result.

I also tried to use this wait, but it did not help:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf (lastMessage.findElement (By.xpath(query))));
```

However when I use this Xpath, it works properly:

```
"(//*[contains(@resource-id,'body_bubble')])[last()]//*[contains(@resource-id, 'delivered_indicator')]"
```

So why it does not work with the nested explicit wait?

[image: pending][image: delivered]

Answer (score 2):

When you use xpath that is to locate nested elements you have to start your query from `.`. Like `String query = ".//*[contains(@resource-id, 'delivered_indicator')]";`

https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: Tried with the dot - doesn't work.

Comment: Can you drill into the method and set breakpoint to line ` List<WebElement> allChildren = element.findElements(childLocator);`? What would be the list content then?

Comment: I've already done the simular thing.
The result is that the `lastMessage` variable still has the "pending_indicator" resource-id in the "footer_delivery_status" container.
Even though the message had been already delivered.

Comment: It seems that the `lastMessage` var is taken the first time I call `wait.until()` with the "pending_indicator" (because at that time the message has not been delivered yet). And then the wait does not update children of the `lastMessage`, because when I call the same wait again in debug evaluation mode after the message was delivered, it works just fine ...

Comment: I hope you understand what I'm trying to say :)
It's just that I'm confused with this behavior. The wait should update children to check if they are visible yet. But in this case the `lastMessage` var stays with the pending indicator, even when the message had been already delivered a long time ago.

Comment: So I don't think there is a problem with Xpath dot and so on.
The main issue is that the children of the `lastMessage` are not updated during wait.
Can I add some parameter to the wait, so it would constantly refresh the children of the variable I defined as a parent? The issue is exactly with the nested wait. Because when I use the wait on the driver itself, the children are updated just fine.

Comment: I would have already used the wait on the driver directly if I could (not searching from the `lastMessage`). But the problem is that there many messages like that, and I wish to know exactly the delivery status of one particular message.

Comment: Probably a message with delivered indicator is technically different message? So basically when you query last message it finishes being last as soon as it gets delivered? Hence you are waiting for the element not in really last message?

Comment: According to the app sources and to the eye, the message still stays the last. Because this is the last element with the resource-id `body_bubble` in view (see the screenshots) and I didn't send any other messages.

Comment: However, I do not dismiss this idea. The element indeed could be replaced. Do you know the way to check it?

Comment: the way to check is to query the items once again after the fail and examine the content in either debug mode or just log them out. Check the number of items for example.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:1**
From your code `“wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy (lastMessage, By.xpath(query)))”`
The expectation of the method `(visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy)` used for checking the child WebElement as a part of parent WebElement to be visible.

Since Nested explicit wait does not work in Appium instead we can use the `visibiltyOf(WebElement element)` or `visiblityOfElementLocated(By locator)` methods.

*visibiltyOf(WebElement element)* - to check whether the element is visible in the DOM or not.
*visiblityOfElementLocated(By locator)* - to check whether the locator is visible in the DOM as well as in the UI.

**Solution:2**
Since Appium DOM is not updated with the latest UI changes, we need to update the DOM which will not automatically update in Appium.
Try the below line of code, before checking the visibility of the element.
Code: `driver.getPageSource();`

As a suggestion, you can also try to swipe to refresh the Appium then get the page source and check the visibility of the element.
**Code:**

```
/**
* @description Is use to swipe from bottom to top. It use to take the mobile window dimension and swipe from bottom to top
* @param step: Nil
*/
public void swipeUpAction() {
try {
               ((AppiumDriver<WebElement>) driver).context("NATIVE_APP");
               Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
               System.out.println(size);
               // Find swipe start and end point from screen's width and height. Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
               int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
               // Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
               int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
               // Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.
               int startx = size.width / 2;
               writeToLogFile("INFO", "starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);
               // Swipe from Bottom to Top.
               ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>) driver).swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
} catch (Exception e) {
               testStepFailed("SwipeElementsScreen failed ");
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
}
```